# Converting split strings into int and adding them

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I have a rather silly question but I couldn't find a fix anywhere. I have a scanner set up that prints lines that are in appropriate format. Here is my while loop within that program:

```
while (fileScan.hasNextLine()){
        String line = null;
        line = fileScan.nextLine();
        String[] element = line.split (":");

            if(line.matches("\\w+\\s?\\w+?\\s?\\w+?\\s[:]\\s\\w+\\s?\\w+?\\s?\\w+?\\s[:]\\s\\d+\\s[:]\\s\\d+")){
                   count++;
                   System.out.println(element[0]+"["+element[2]+"]\t"+"|"+element[1]+"["+element[3]+" ]");

            } else {
            invalidLines++;
                System.out.println("Line declined.");

            }
    }
```

What would I need to do in order to keep adding all the values of element[2] (assuming they are all strings, I do understand that converting them to int is necessary) and print a single line at the end with a total sum of added element[2]'s.

If you could just simply point me in the right direction I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a sum field before you start scanning through the file, and then when a line match occurs, do `sum += Integer.parseInt(element[2]);` and after you're done scanning, print the value of sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had to trim the values because it was throwing an Exception error otherwise so                                         `sum +=Integer.parseInt(element[2].trim());`